# Is log4cplus dependent on log4j?

Tags: logging

log4cplus is a simple to use C++ logging API providing thread-safe, flexible, and arbitrarily granular control over log management and configuration. It is modelled after the Java log4j API. So, is the log4cplus framework dependent on log4j framework internally or they are completely independent?